# Get owner password of pdf from qpdf decryption?

Tags: pdf, encryption, decryption

I have a pdf file which I removed the owner password using

```
qpdf --decrypt encrypted_document.pdf decrypted_document.pdf
```

However, I need to know what the owner password is. Did qpdf find the onwer password? How do I print it out?

Comment: “Did qpdf find the owner password?” - No, that isn’t possible. “How do I print it out?” - You can’t

Answer (score -1):

The qpdf utility converts a PDF file to another PDF file.
The decrypted PDF is a new document and doesn't inherit the metadata
from the old file.

If there was an Owner password in the old document, it was not
transferred to the new one, so is lost.